# Laravel get detailed information about the Exception

Tags: php, laravel, exception

I have changed the default Laravel error template to my custom template and can able to display the error message `Undefined variable: requesteee` (see red box 2) with `$e->getMessage()` method, how to get the details shown in red box 1 ?

[image: Default Laravel error template]

Below is my custom error template

[image: Custom error template]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel uses the [Whoops](https://github.com/filp/whoops) package to display user-friendly, understandable errors.

You should use that if you want your custom template to look like laravel whoops page.